# Push notifications in my app using FCM without firebase console

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to use push notifications in my app (Ionic) with Firebase Cloud Messaging without firebase console. I need to send notifications directly from my app.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API for sending messages to devices, groups of devices, and topics (that clients can subscribe to). For an example, see the page in the Firebase documentation on [sending your first message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message#send_a_notification_message).

Note that sending messaging **to** an app requires that your specify the FCM *server key*. As its name implies, this key should only be used on a server you control or an otherwise trusted environment. That's why the examples in the documentation are CURL calls, which you can easily run from your development machine or server.